# vagrant up won't start Virtual Machine

Tags: vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

I am working on a Laravel project and was trying to referencing another project on GitHub. In the process of trying to open that project, my computer stalled and I restarted. Now this pops up every time I use `vagrant up`.

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): found a tab character that violate intendation while scanning a plain scalar at line 22 column 11 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
    from C:/Users/ericc/Homestead/Vagrantfile:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `new'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:740:in `vagrantfile'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:486:in `host'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:208:in `block in action_runner'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:473:in `hook'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:722:in `unload'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you look at C:/Users/ericc/Homestead/Vagrantfile and check there's no tab whats on Line 20 of this file ?

Comment: There's no tab, only spaces and I tried removing them.  Then I tried running `vagrant up` again. then this pops up `bash: $'\302\216vagrant': command not found
`

Comment: I've solved the problem by redoing the whole project.

Answer (score 3):

when you see this error, you should look the homestead.yaml file. there is space or enter extra.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's very hard to find the character that is messing with yml file.
Copy entire content of the following file and paste that in your `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml`

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/homestead/master/src/stubs/Homestead.yaml